# Pause Flutter Countdown Timer

Tags: dart, flutter

I have been playing with Dart Timer Class that I got it to work in its very basic form, however I am stuck trying to add a pause function to it. I have looked into their documentations, but their is not much about their Timer class...

Is there any way I can pause and resume the timer/countdown on click? This is what I have achieved so far:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}


class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  Timer _timer;
  int _start = 10;

  void startTimer() {
    const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 1);
    _timer = new Timer.periodic(
        oneSec,
            (Timer timer) => setState(() {
          if (_start < 1) {
            timer.cancel();
          } else {
            _start = _start - 1;
          }
        }));
  }


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Timer test")),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                startTimer();
              },
              child: Text("start"),
            ),
            Text("$_start")
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

There is no built-in `pause` function, since the `Timer` class is mainly intended for scheduling blocks of code for later.

What is your use case? The [`Stopwatch`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Stopwatch-class.html) class has pause and resume funtionality.

Answer (score 8):

I just uploaded this package to implement exactly this: https://pub.dev/packages/pausable_timer

```
// It starts paused
final timer = PausableTimer(Duration(seconds: 1), () => print('Fired!'));
timer.start();
timer.pause();
timer.start();
```

There is also an [issue requesting the feature in Dart itself](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/43329), but it doesn't look like it will be added soon.

Comment: In my case I want the `timer` to run every 1 sec and freeze it when I want but I realized your library only works to make a code run after a particular amount of time has passed

Comment: All you have to do is use `timer.reset(); timer.start();` in the timer callback to start it again (make it periodic). Here is an example on how to implement a countdown with it, which is the same you want except that the timer will end after a number of repetitions: https://pub.dev/packages/pausable_timer#example-pausable-countdown-implementation

Answer (score 4):

Working flutter example with pause and vibrations is below ([source](https://github.com/karolzlot/countdown-example-vibration-pause))

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:vibration/vibration.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: CountdownCard()));

class CountdownCard extends StatefulWidget {
// This widget is the root of your application.

@override
_CountdownCardState createState() => _CountdownCardState();
}

class _CountdownCardState extends State<CountdownCard> {
Timer _timer;
int _start = 0;
bool _vibrationActive = false;

void startTimer(int timerDuration) {
    if (_timer != null) {
    _timer.cancel();
    cancelVibrate();
    }
    setState(() {
    _start = timerDuration;
    });
    const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 1);
    print('test');
    _timer = new Timer.periodic(
    oneSec,
    (Timer timer) => setState(
        () {
        if (_start < 1) {
            timer.cancel();
            print('alarm');
            vibrate();
        } else {
            _start = _start - 1;
        }
        },
    ),
    );
}

void cancelVibrate() {
    _vibrationActive = false;
    Vibration.cancel();
}

void vibrate() async {
    _vibrationActive = true;
    if (await Vibration.hasVibrator()) {
    while (_vibrationActive) {
        Vibration.vibrate(duration: 1000);
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    }
    }
}

void pauseTimer() {
    if (_timer != null) _timer.cancel();
}

void unpauseTimer() => startTimer(_start);

@override
void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Countdown'),
        ),
        body: Wrap(children: <Widget>[
        Column(
            children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                startTimer(10);
                },
                child: Text("start"),
            ),
            Text("$_start"),
            RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                pauseTimer();
                },
                child: Text("pause"),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                unpauseTimer();
                },
                child: Text("unpause"),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                cancelVibrate();
                },
                child: Text("stop alarm"),
            ),
            ],
        ),
        ]));
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

variables we define
start timer on page opening.
timer off when page is closed.

if the screen is touched, the variable duration becomes true and the timer stops counting down

```
     Timer? _timer;
     int _start = 200;
     bool duration = false;
     Duration oneSec = const Duration(milliseconds: 10);
```

````
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    startTimer();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer!.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

 ```
````

```
    GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {},
              onTapDown: (e) {
                setState(() {
                  duration = true;
                });
              },
              onHorizontalDragEnd: (e) {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              onTapUp: (e) {
                setState(() {
                  duration = false;
                });
              },
              child:Text("demo page")}
```

```
  void startTimer() {
    _timer = new Timer.periodic(
      oneSec,
      (Timer timer) {
        if (_start == 0) {
          setState(() {
            timer.cancel();
            Navigator.pop(context);
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            duration == false ? _start-- : null;
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```